# Adding details and hyperlinks in edits

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I proposed an edit to an answer, and it was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9809088). What am I not getting here?

## The Edit

I added what I thought was relevant information:

1. The fact that `strtoumax` and `strtoimax` are C99 functions. Not all C compilers support C99, especially in the embedded realm.
2. A relevant hyperlink as a reference for the functions.

### My Reasoning

On (2), the [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) page says, among other reasons, we should edit posts

> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

It also says

> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without *changing* that meaning)

Does (1) fall under clarification?

## Rejection Reasons

The edit was rejected by 3 of 4 reviewers. Two selected as their reason,

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

(I'm assuming that "post" means the answer I attempted to edit, not the question...)

I was not intending to address the author of the answer; I was adding the detail for the benefit of future readers. The answer was good, and my detail far too small to be its own answer. And why should readers have to trudge through comments to see what can easily be included in the main text?

The other reviewer selected as his/her reason,

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I'd say it makes it more accurate, as noted in (1) above. None of the other descriptors in the first sentence were my goals. Not superfluous, per (1). And I don't see how it harms readability.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at the edit itself, I personally think it should have been approved.

Comment: Looks like a good edit. I've edited it in.

Comment: It helps to remember that edit reviewers are just members too, so they can make incorrect judgements just as much as post authors can. I've seen plenty of edits tagged way off base and can only assume some people are tearing through the review queue blindly choosing options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the author is an active user of the site, you may have better luck leaving a comment for them.  That would give the author the opportunity to update their answer to include that C99 clarification! :)

I can see how a reviewer could get the impression that the *C99 functions* addition does appear to be a reply to the author.  I can also see how a single change to a 4-year-old answer might appear to be superfluous.

The reviewers only have an edit comment to go by, and if an edit gives the reviewer a mistaken impression, they're likely going to reject it.  It's unfortunate in cases like this, but we can only read your meta post, not your mind :)

I do want to say thanks for your edit!  Your intent and effort is appreciated :)

## Update:

A reviewer can't be expected to accurately determine whether your edit is meant

- (as a reply) for the author,
- (a correction) for both the author and future readers, or
- (an improvement) for future readers.

**In two of those three possibilities, your edit could be mistaken as a reply to the author.**  Without an edit comment that clearly explains the purpose of the edit, it would be easy for a reviewer to misjudge whether (or not) you are replying.

**As for being superfluous, a reviewer may misjudge whether your edit was trivial or obvious (unnecessary).**  Again, a clarification in the edit comment might help to explain that the functions aren't widely available for most compilers.

What you see from one perspective may appear completely different to a reviewer.

The edit comment is generally the first thing a good reviewer reads, and it can influence whether an edit is approved or rejected.

Comment: Can you elaborate on these parts? "I can see how a reviewer could get the impression that the C99 functions addition does appear to be a reply to the author. I can also see how a single change to a 4-year-old answer might appear to be superfluous."

Comment: Also, re - "That would give the author the opportunity to update their answer to include that C99 clarification!" Why does it matter who updates it?

Comment: @cp.engr Although [you consider it as a waste of space to comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307847/adding-details-and-hyperlinks-in-edits/307851?noredirect=1#comment257400_307855) instead of directly revising the author's post yourself, others may see it as consideration shown the author by giving them the opportunity to improve their answer.  It's possible that they'd make *additional changes* that would go beyond your edit.  I know I'd prefer the chance to improve an answer of mine if someone pointed out a shortcoming/omission to me.

Comment: Good considerations, thanks for explaining.

Comment: Still curious on my first comment above.

Comment: @cp.engr Your first comment led to me improving the answer.  I didn't plan for that, but perhaps that also illustrates why it may matter who updates an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification/update. I can see a more explicit explanation might've helped. I may have assumed too much subject matter expertise from the reviewers, and didn't clarify intent. Re why it matters, haha, good point. :)

Answer (score 7):

The info about C99 is useful, but it *does* appear to modify the original author's intent, so I can understand it being rejected.

Reviewers should skip posts they don't understand, OTOH, they aren't expected to be *experts* in the topic, so they can't be expected to know whether such additions are technically correct or not, even if you provide a hyperlink for reference. (Also, while many reviewers do open questions for closer inspection on border-line cases, they aren't obliged to do so). So it's reasonable for them to reject an edit that looks like it's putting words into the original author's mouth.

Making edits that appear to conflict with the original author's intentions, even when they improve the post, is generally *not* the SO way. I may *believe* that my info is better than your info. But I might be wrong. :) So we use comment, votes, and alternative answers, and allow the community to achieve consensus that way. This democratic process may not be perfect, but it avoids the unpleasantness and chaos of never-ending edit wars.

For minor corrections, your first step should be to offer your suggestion in a comment, and only propose an edit if the author doesn't respond after an adequate time, making it clear in your edit comments that your info corrects a flaw in the existing answer and that the author hasn't responded to your comment.

If the author is no longer active on SO (which is easy to check) then go ahead with your proposed edit, but you should still mention in your edit comment that you're adding important info and that the author is no longer active.

For larger corrections, or corrections that aren't amenable to being presented in comments, just write a new answer, perhaps with a comment  attached to the old answer that links to your new answer. And if you feel that the info in the old answer is misleading or dangerous, you should consider downvoting it.

Comment: If adding information that someone didn't think of counts as 'overriding their intent', that's seriously counterproductive to other stated goals such as clarification or extra links, so I kinda hope that's a misinterpretation really. And if you ask me, any author who would get into a petty edit war over something that merely enhances their post is not necessarily the type of member we'd want to encourage anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d: I'm not saying don't edit; I'm saying first attempt to get the OA (original author) to edit, when possible. Sometimes it's obvious that the added info is correct & improves the answer, or it's easy to supply a link to docs that support the editor's position, but that's not always the case. However, we can't expect edit reviewers to have the expertise to make decisions about that sort of thing. OTOH, even people who can make edits without going through the review process should still first attempt to get the OA to update via comments, IMHO: I always do, even with trivial edits.

Comment: In what way does it appear that I was trying to modify the OA's intent?

Comment: @PM2Ring, "I'm saying first attempt to get the OA (original author) to edit, when possible." Why? My thought is why waste space in comments when I can easily add the content to the post itself.

Comment: @PM2Ring, scratch that last comment - PetahChristian already explained. Still curious about my first comment, though (re OA's intent).

Comment: @cp.engr: The OP says that those functions are _standard_. But you're saying they're _standard C99 functions_. Ideally, a reviewer should understand that your info isn't contradicting the OA's info, it's adding useful detail. And if the reviewer doesn't know enough about C to realise that, they should skip the review rather than rejecting it.

Comment: (cont) But in practice, reviewers like to clear the review queues and prefer to err on the side of caution. So good edit comments are vital when you add information to a post; they aren't so critical when you just correct grammar or spelling, or convert existing content to hyperlinks.

Comment: More helpful perspective - thanks.